# Citizenship Amendment Act(CAA) is unsecular? (currently trending in india)

Tags: india, human-rights, indian-constitutional-law

India considers themself a secular nation.

> It amended the Citizenship Act of 1955 by providing a path to Indian
>   citizenship for members of Hindu, Sikh, Buddhist, Jain, Parsi, and
>   Christian religious minorities, who had fled persecution from
>   Pakistan, Bangladesh and Afghanistan before December 2014. Muslims
>   were not given such eligibility. The act was the first instance
>   of religion being overtly used as a criterion for citizenship under
>   Indian nationality law.

There is a lot of protest going in India against this law. you can read more about the law here ([wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizenship_(Amendment)_Act,_2019)).

Most people are saying it is religious discrimination and it violates [Article 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_14_of_the_Constitution_of_India).

The government is saying it is for the persecuted minorities of those countries three countries and it is not related to Indian Muslims. people belong to other religions are facing persecution in those countries. They are also ignoring the fact that Muslims religion also has a different caste-like [Shia Muslims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Shi%27ism), [Ahmadiyyas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Ahmadis), etc and they are also facing persecution. First of all, it will affect Indians because all those who get Indian citizenship with the help of this law will able to get benefits from all government policies.

India shares a border with other countries too like Sri-lanka, Myanmar, China, Nepal but they are only picking Muslims majority countries in this law.

Spokesperson for the [UN High Commissioner](https://www.indiatoday.in/india/story/un-voices-concern-over-violence-in-india-against-caa-urges-respect-for-freedom-of-expression-1629399-2019-12-18) for Human Rights had said in Geneva that it is "concerned" that the CAA is "fundamentally discriminatory in nature".

Government of India still haven’t mend any rules and regulation plus procedure on How they will go ahead with CAA. The Supreme Court of India has given a deadline of 22nd Jan 2020 to HMA to give the brief regarding the same.

After going through the brief if Judiciary finds out that it's violating any rights of the Constitution of India than they have a right to scrap this law.

they are saying it will not affect Indians but they are also going to launch NRC (National register of citizen) which is also considered as a major issue because according to NRC you cannot be a citizen of India any more if you are categorized as a doubtful citizen. you can also become a doubtful citizen because of spelling mistakes in your documents.

But Speaking of NRC it is totally waste of money because if there comes out some illegal immigrants with no proper documents it would be really difficult for the Government to prove other countries these people belong to you and take back, so they will be sent into detention camps and in this detention camps those refugees will have free shelter and food which will be burn from the taxpayer accounts which only round off to 6.8 Crore people who are just 5% of the population (Yes these are the numbers which actually pay taxes in their ITR) which will affect our economy really worse and our economy is not at all in good shape. So the government if want to bring NRC then they have to find the best and cost-effective measure and resources, because NRC all along in Assam just cost roughly around 1300 crore. So just imagine how much will it cost in the entire country.

Comment: What’s the question?

Comment: @DaleM is the LAW secular or not?

Comment: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secularism

Comment: I think this is the gazette link found on internet... 
  http://egazette.nic.in/WriteReadData/2019/214646.pdf

Comment: Flagged as not really being a question, this is more of a rambling than an actual question.